# dplyr is not working properly when using group by in it

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

Am calculating error rates between two different forecasting methods.
My basic approach is to get group by `nk` and calculate the errors to compare and choose the one which have less error rate value. The issue is am getting `MAP1E_arima_ds` and `MAPE_cagr_ds` is all the same value some how the group_by function is not working while calculating.

Here is something I tried

```
  group_by(nk) %>%
  mutate(MAP1E_arima_ds=sum(temp2$ABS_arima_error_ds)/nrow(temp2)) %>%
  mutate(MAPE_cagr_ds=sum(temp2$ABS_cagr_error_ds)/nrow(temp2))




So finally expected like


         nk         MAP1E_arima_ds      MAPE_cagr_ds
       1-G0175      value_x                value_y
       1-H0182       value_z               value_a

so that I can compare error rate and choose forecasting method with less error rate.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think what you are looking for is this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(nk) %>%
  summarise(MAP1E_arima_ds=sum(ABS_arima_error_ds)/n(), 
            MAPE_cagr_ds=sum(ABS_cagr_error_ds)/n())

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    nk      MAP1E_arima_ds MAPE_cagr_ds
#  <chr>            <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 1-G0175          14.7          3.38
#2 1-H0182           2.91         7.40
```

which is actually `mean`

```
df %>%
  group_by(nk) %>%
  summarise(MAP1E_arima_ds = mean(ABS_arima_error_ds), 
            MAPE_cagr_ds = mean(ABS_cagr_error_ds))
```

Moreover, after copying your `dput` it seems that your data is already grouped by `nk`, so the following would also give the same result

```
df %>%
   summarise(MAP1E_arima_ds=mean(ABS_arima_error_ds), 
             MAPE_cagr_ds=mean(ABS_cagr_error_ds))
```